# Bash mv not a directory

Tags: bash, mv

I have part of my script that goes like this:

```
while read line  
do 
code=`echo ${line}  | awk  '{print $1}'`
awk -f ${supscript}/rearrange.sh < ${base}/${code}  
mv temp_output* "$code"temp_output* 
done < filelist
```

The script is working; the only problem is that when it is trying to rename the file I got the following error message:

```
mv: target `pollcodetemp_output*' is not a directory
```

Maybe it is something related with the IFS. I try to specify this at the beginning of the script as:

```
IFS='
'
```

But it is not working. I'm using a Windows text editor but I have already removed the CR.

Comment: Use indentation. Use `$()` instead of backticks. Quote your variables. AWK accepts input filenames as arguments without needing redirection. Use `-r` with `read` almost always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you just need:

```
mv temp_output* "$code"
```

This will move the files named `temp_output*` in the current directory to the directory specified in the variable `$code`.

However, if `$code` is a file, then you need to look for a `rename` command (there are several versions, with different syntaxes), or you need to use an inner loop:

```
for file in temp_output*
do mv "$file" "$code$file"
done
```

Comment: $code is a file. I went for the inner loop solution which works pretty fine and achieved was what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why is this not working with a file and we have to use inner loop if it is just one file?

Comment: @HrvojeT: you only get the "is not a directory" message if `mv` is invoked with at least three arguments and the last argument is not a directory. In context, that means that the glob pattern `temp_output*` matches at least two file names, presumably generated by the `awk` script.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to move multiple files to a name that is not a directory, which is not possible. This happens because you seem to be trying to rename from a wildcard pattern *to* a wildcard pattern, which is also not possible. I won't be guessing what exactly you're trying to accomplish, so I cannot give you any additional advice.