# Using bash scripting how can I trim the last 12 characters from a folder containing files

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Using bash scripting how can I trim the last 12 characters from a folder containing files like these?

```
"this is a test-FhgSDjekcdh.txt"     -> "this is a test.txt"
"this also is a file-ZHSDjekcdh.txt" -> "this is also a file.txt"
```

The characters in front of the `-xfshfsgdhdsf.txt` are going to be different for each file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
    for file in *.txt; do
        mv "$file" "${file%%????????????????}.txt"
    done
```

There are 16 question marks: 12 for the characters you wish to remove, and 4 for the `.txt` extension.

Comment: mv: target `Finish.mp4' is not a directory
mv: target `Masterclass.mp4' is not a directory
mv: target `Need.mp4' is not a directory
mv: target `Bass.mp4' is not a directory
mv: target `Effects.mp4' is not a directory
mv: target `Berlin.mp4' is not a directory
mv: target `M.mp4' is not a directory
mv: target `9.mp4' is not a directory

Comment: I am trying it on a folder of video files i need to rename without the "-HGhgsgsdfcvb"  they are .mp4

Comment: @j-techlogic: Maybe you need quotation marks, as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/11152444/318716.  Also, as a debugging test, replace `mv` with `echo mv`, to see the resulting commands.

Comment: Problem with missing quotes fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
sed -r 's/^([^-]+)\-.*(\.txt)$/\1\2/'
```

Comment: Adjusted the regex to make it support various file names

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 28: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add -r, try it now

Comment: assuming there is only 1 "-" in the file name

Comment: Works fine with more than one "-": 
echo "file-fsaf23-4s.txt" | sed -r 's/^([^-]+)\-.*(\.txt)$/\1
\2/'
file.txt

Answer (score 0):

A more general way that can extend to any file of the form "xxx-xxx.xxx" using `awk`'s built-in split function:

```
for file in /path/to/dir/*
do
awk '{ split($0, arr1, "-"); split($0, arr2, "."); print arr1[1]"."arr2[2]; }' <(echo "$file") 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

from your sample (where the last 12 char are always the same)

```
sed -n 's/.\{12\}/.txt/'
```